# Android Emulator 4.2 (API Level 17) "Unfortunately camera has stopped" When try to access camera from the main menu

Tags: android-emulator

I'm using Android 4.2 (API Level 17) emulator.

Whenever I clicked on the Camera, I got the following error message :

**Unfortunately, camera has stopped**

**These are the logcat errors :**

```
E/CameraService(40): CameraService::connect X (pid 862) rejected (invalid cameraId 0).
E/CameraHolder(862): fail to connect Camera
E/CameraHolder(862): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
E/CameraHolder(862): at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
E/CameraHolder(862): at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:340)
E/CameraHolder(862): at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:302)
E/CameraHolder(862): at com.android.camera.CameraHolder.open(CameraHolder.java:131)
E/CameraHolder(862): at com.android.camera.Util.openCamera(Util.java:267)
E/CameraHolder(862): at com.android.camera.Camera$4.run(Camera.java:1100)
E/AndroidRuntime(862): java.lang.RuntimeException: openCamera failed
E/AndroidRuntime(862): at com.android.camera.Util.openCamera(Util.java:272)
E/AndroidRuntime(862): at com.android.camera.Camera$4.run(Camera.java:1100)
E/AndroidRuntime(862): Caused by: com.android.camera.CameraHardwareException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
E/AndroidRuntime(862): at com.android.camera.CameraHolder.open(CameraHolder.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(862): at com.android.camera.Util.openCamera(Util.java:267)
E/AndroidRuntime(862): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
E/AndroidRuntime(862): at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(862): at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:340)
E/AndroidRuntime(862): at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:302)
E/AndroidRuntime(862): at com.android.camera.CameraHolder.open(CameraHolder.java:131)
```

I tried various solutions. But no luck :(

No one has given a working solution for this problem so far. Please give me a hint

- Webcam : Dell Integrated webcam
- OS : windows 8 Professional 64 bit version

Cheers !!!

Comment: Can you try starting the emulator on the command line? emulator -avd "your avd name" Also, can you include your avd settings if it still does not work?

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't care anymore but this was one of the first ones i got when i googled the same problem so in case anyone else runs into this i found that my problem was that i had selected no camera in the AVD (seems to be default)

[image: Android emulator no camera selected]